# Return Results From Select Statement and Store Count In Variable

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql

I am wanting to execute my select statement, but also store the returned row count into a variable.  This is how my DDL is set-up, how can I store the row count from my Select statement in my variable`@returnedrows`

```
Declare @returnedrows int;

Insert Into pinkpurplegreen (field1, field2, field3, field4, field5)
Select field1, field2, field3, field4, field5
FROM blue

Select * FROM pinkpurplegreen
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would need to select the [@@ROWCOUNT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-be/library/ms187316.aspx) variable

```
CREATE TABLE dba_152082 (field1 int NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO dba_152082 (field1) VALUES (1),(1), (2);

DECLARE @numberofrows int;

SELECT * FROM dba_152082;

SELECT @numberofrows = @@ROWCOUNT;

PRINT @numberofrows;

DROP TABLE dba_152082;
```

You should be able to verify the value of your variable in the messages tab after you run that.